# How to Overlay two documents at run time

Tags: java, pdfbox

I have a requirement to add watermark text at run time, ie. at the time of document creation i need to add watermark text. My initial approach was to get all the pages from document and add my text on those pages. Id did work, but the problem is where ever my watermark message comes it is hiding my page content. Please see code for my initial approach.

```
  List pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    float fontSize = 70.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
        PDRectangle pageSize = page.findMediaBox();
        float stringWidth = pdfFont.getStringWidth(text) * fontSize
                / 1000f;
        // calculate to center of the page
        int rotation = page.findRotation();
        boolean rotate = degree > 0;
        float pageWidth = rotate ? pageSize.getHeight() : pageSize
                .getWidth();
        float pageHeight = rotate ? pageSize.getWidth() : pageSize
                .getHeight();
        double centeredXPosition = rotate ? pageHeight / 2f
                : (pageWidth - stringWidth) / 2f;
        double centeredYPosition = rotate ? (pageWidth - stringWidth) / 2f
                : pageHeight / 2f;
        // append the content to the existing stream
        PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
                document, page, true, true, true);
        contentStream.beginText();
        // set font and font size
        contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
        // set text color to red
        contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(240, 240, 240);
        if (rotate) {
            // rotate the text according to the page rotation
            contentStream.setTextRotation(degree, x, y);
        } else {
            contentStream.setTextTranslation(centeredXPosition,
                    centeredYPosition);
        }
        contentStream.drawString(text);
        contentStream.endText();
        contentStream.close();
```

I have read about Overlay and I have tried it, so I tried changing my approach, bcz i think only Overlay can fulfill my requirement. My present approach is:

```
    public PDDocument createWatermarkText() {
    PDDocument watermarkDoc = new PDDocument();
    PDPage watermarkPage = new PDPage();
    try {

        watermarkDoc.addPage(watermarkPage);
        PDPageContentStream content = new PDPageContentStream(watermarkDoc,
                watermarkPage);
        content.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
        content.beginText();
        content.moveTextPositionByAmount(x, y);
        content.setNonStrokingColor(255, 0, 0);
        PDRectangle pageSize = watermarkPage.findMediaBox();
        float stringWidth = pdfFont.getStringWidth(text) * fontSize / 1000f;
        // int rotation = page.findRotation();
        boolean rotate = degree > 0;
        float pageWidth = rotate ? pageSize.getHeight() : pageSize
                .getWidth();
        float pageHeight = rotate ? pageSize.getWidth() : pageSize
                .getHeight();
        double centeredXPosition = rotate ? pageHeight / 2f
                : (pageWidth - stringWidth) / 2f;
        double centeredYPosition = rotate ? (pageWidth - stringWidth) / 2f
                : pageHeight / 2f;
        content.setTextRotation(degree, x, y);

        content.drawString(text);
        content.endText();
        content.close();
        // ColumnText.showTextAligned(writer.getDirectContentUnder(), align,
        // new Phrase(text, pdfFont), x, y,
        // degree);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return watermarkDoc;
}
```

and then calling this method

```
     PDDocument wDoc = createWatermarkText();
            //document.addPage(page);
             Overlay overlay = new Overlay();

             overlay.overlay(wDoc, document);
```

but this approach is not working out, and Im getting blank pdf. Any help higly appreciated.

Comment: *the problem is where ever my watermark message comes it is hiding my page content* - in which way do you want it instead? Should your page content cover the water mark? Or do you want transparency?

Comment: I want my watermark text to be under my page content.

Comment: Ok. I'll look into that as soon as I'm in office today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer attempts to make the original approach of the OP work.*

The problem of the original approach,

> where ever my watermark message comes it is hiding my page content.

is caused by the fact that the PDFBox `PDPageContentStream` constructors add the new stream as *last* content stream, so its operations also are executed last and consequentially cover content drawn before.

To push the new content under the existing content, therefore, we must move the new stream to the front position among the page content streams.

To be able to do so, I first change the existing code: I enclose the watermark drawing code in `saveGraphicsState` and `restoreGraphicsState`. This is necessary to protect the original content from being influenced by state changes by the the mark drawing code, e.g. text color changes.

```
...
PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(
        document, page, true, true, true);
contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
contentStream.beginText();
// set font and font size
contentStream.setFont(pdfFont, fontSize);
// set text color to red
contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(240, 240, 240);
if (rotate) {
    // rotate the text according to the page rotation
    contentStream.setTextRotation(degree, x, y);
} else {
    contentStream.setTextTranslation(centeredXPosition,
            centeredYPosition);
}
contentStream.drawString(text);
contentStream.endText();
contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
contentStream.close();
...
```

With this change in place, we merely need to call the following method to push the watermark under the pre-existing content:

```
void pushUnder(PDDocument document)
{
    List<?> pages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
    float fontSize = 70.0f;
    for (int i = 0; i < pages.size(); i++) {
        PDPage page = (PDPage) pages.get(i);
        COSBase contents = page.getCOSDictionary().getDictionaryObject(COSName.CONTENTS);
        if (contents instanceof COSStreamArray)
        {
            COSStreamArray contentsArray = (COSStreamArray) contents;
            COSArray newArray = new COSArray();
            newArray.add(contentsArray.get(0));
            newArray.add(contentsArray.get(contentsArray.getStreamCount() - 1));

            for (int j = 1; j < contentsArray.getStreamCount() - 1; j++)
            {
                newArray.add(contentsArray.get(j));
            }

            COSStreamArray newStreamArray = new COSStreamArray(newArray);
            page.getCOSDictionary().setItem(COSName.CONTENTS, newStreamArray);
        }
    }
}
```

*([UnderlayText.java](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-pdfbox1/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/pdfbox1/content/UnderlayText.java))*

(If you look closely at the method, you'll see that we don't move the new stream to the first position but only to the second. We do so because the `new PDPageContentStream(document, page, true, true, true)` constructor call actually creates two new streams, one at the first position, one at the last one, the first one saving the graphics state, the last one restoring it and then containing your operations. Moving the latter before the former would result in a restore graphics state operations at the beginning which would be an error.)